# Append a function's return values to an existing array

Tags: python, arrays, append

```
def mathfunction():
    return 1, 2

(temp1, temp2) = mathfunction()
array1.append(temp1)
array2.append(temp2)
temp1 = []
temp2 = []
print array1, array2
```

As you can see this simple code appends the values from `mathfunction` to existing arrays. My question is if there's a way to do this without using extra variables (`temp1`, `temp2`).

Comment: If you're worried about efficiency, why do you create two empty lists to dereference objects you've literally just added to some other lists? The temporary assignment is fine, but **use better names**, `temp1` tells the reader nothing (nor, for that matter, does `array1`!) Also you don't need the parentheses - `temp1, temp2 = mathfunction()` does the job. Do you actually have a measurable performance problem here?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yeah, you all are right. My bad.

Comment: Not given that you need to append them to different lists. Is there actually a *problem* with naming the return values? This seems a lot like premature optimisation.

Comment: You call them `array` but you don't use `numpy` so really it's just a python list. What do you mean by "efficient"? Speed or memory, or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `zip` the arrays and the function and use a loop:

```
>>> array1 = []
>>> array2 = []
>>> def mathfunction():
...     return 1, 2
...
>>> for a,r in zip((array1,array2),mathfunction()):
...     a.append(r)
...
>>> array1
[1]
>>> array2
[2]
```

Comment: @Chrisp actually, this creates two extra variables too, `a, r` and is probably *less efficient* since it has the loop overhead which isn't necessary here... unpacking a returned tuple is the way to go.

Comment: For bonus points extract out `def appender((lst, item)): lst.append(item)`. Then it's reusable! And you can `map(appender, zip((array1, array2), mathfunction()))` for the side effects and reap your just rewards.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I hope you are joking!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - It creates two temporary variables, but that number doesn't grow if there are more lists and more objects returned from `mathfunction`. Of course, if you wanted to eliminate any temporary variables being added to the current scope, you could do `[a.append(r) for a,r in zip((array1,array2), mathfunction())]`, but that would be unpythonic.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga of course; for Python 3.x compatibility I'd recommend `def appender(t): t[LIST_INDEX].append(t[ITEM_INDEX])` where `LIST_INDEX, ITEM_INDEX = range(2)`.

Comment: @Chrisp but that doesn't make syntactic sense; you can't assign to a function call. Shorter code is not always better code! Spend your time optimising the things that *matter*.

Comment: @Chrisp what is so verbose about your original code? If you really just have two temporary variables, then this for-loop is about twice as slow.

Comment: @Chrisp - If it runs fast enough for your purposes, and if it's clear enough that you think you could immediately understand what it's doing after forgetting about it for six months, it's good enough.

Comment: i have no idea what your talking about, i was merely looking for a simplier way to write my section of code, your answer should suffice, thank you